# android: what is needed to restore Activity status after back-navigation?

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation, back

Disclaimer: I'm a seasoned programmer, but an almost complete newbie to Android; I might be asking the obvious.

I have a rather simple GUI for my tentative App.

Specifically I have a topmost `Switch` to turn my application on/off.

At startup switch is off.

When it is on I can select from menu a child `MonitorActivity` to display what's going on (some kind of a running log).

`MonitorActivity` is properly linked to parent, so I can go back to `MainActivity`.

So far, so good. Everything works.

Problem is when I back-navigate `MainActivity` is completely reset, as if started anew; in particular my on/off `Switch` is back to `off` position.

My understanding of [relevant documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack) is `MainActivity` should have been stopped; relevant snippet is:

> The previous activity remains in the stack, but is stopped. When an
>   activity stops, the system retains the current state of its user
>   interface. When the user presses the Back button, the current activity
>   is popped from the top of the stack (the activity is destroyed) and
>   the previous activity resumes (the previous state of its UI is
>   restored).

From this I understand I shouldn't be doing anything specific to restore `MainActivity` status; is this correct?

Should I post my `AndroidMainfest.xml` (or other files)?

**UPDATE** (as requested):

I am following strictly the pattern from [MyFirstApp](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity):

- Start `MonitorActivity` from `MainActivity` using `startActivity(intent)`.
- Back-naviagtion using left-arrow on main menu (using: `<activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">` in `AndroidManifest.xml`)

*NOTE*: This is exactly the behavior of `MyFirstApp`: When coming back from `DisplayMessageActivity` the content of `EditText` widget is gone (even if none explicitly clears it).

Perhaps I should rename question: "How can I preserve 'message' after 'Send' in 'MyFirstApp'?"

*UPDATE2*: I overrided several callbacks to trace what really happens;
here's the log (comments inline, look for '<<<<<'):

```
02/27 16:05:24: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t -p it.condarelli.myfirstapp /home/mcon/AndroidStudioProjects/MyfirstApp/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_2.apk 
Split APKs installed in 483 ms
$ adb shell am start -n "it.condarelli.myfirstapp/it.condarelli.myfirstapp.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: it.condarelli.myfirstapp | it.condarelli.myfirstapp.test
Waiting for application to come online: it.condarelli.myfirstapp | it.condarelli.myfirstapp.test
Connecting to it.condarelli.myfirstapp
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/elli.myfirstap: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
W/elli.myfirstap: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
W/ActivityThread: Application it.condarelli.myfirstapp is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
    waiting for debugger to settle...
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8603', transport: 'socket'
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/chatty: uid=10085(it.condarelli.myfirstapp) identical 2 lines
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1354)
W/elli.myfirstap: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
I/chatty: uid=10085(it.condarelli.myfirstapp) identical 10 lines
W/elli.myfirstap: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
I/MainActivity: onCreate(null)             <<<<< This is App start
W/elli.myfirstap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
I/MainActivity: onStart()
I/MainActivity: onResume()
I/MainActivity: onPostResume()
D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xcb81c0c0, tid 17161
I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
    android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xde3584a0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xde3584a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xcb943060)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xde3584a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xcb943060)
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2344 bytes, containing 1 windows, 8 views
I/MainActivity: onPause()                  <<<<< This is first message after I pressed 'Send' button.
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@18e99e1
I/DisplayMessageActivity: onStart()
I/DisplayMessageActivity: onResume()
I/DisplayMessageActivity: onPostResume()
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xde3584a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xcb943060)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xde3584a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xcb943060)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xde3584a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xcb943060)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xde3584a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xcb943060)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xde3584a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xcb943060)
I/MainActivity: onStop()
I/MainActivity: onSaveInstanceState()      <<<<< This is where log stops while DisplayMessageActivity is focused
I/DisplayMessageActivity: onPause()        <<<<< This is first message after Back-navigation
I/MainActivity: onDestroy()                <<<<< WHY THIS NOW??
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@bd33145
I/MainActivity: onCreate(null)             <<<<< MainActivity is recreated from scratch
I/MainActivity: onStart()
I/MainActivity: onResume()
I/MainActivity: onPostResume()
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xde3584a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xcb943060)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xde3584a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xcb943060)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xde3584a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xcb943060)
I/DisplayMessageActivity: onStop()
I/DisplayMessageActivity: onDestroy()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think that you use an intent for go from MonitorActivity to MainActivity, could you please add?

Comment: @GianlucaBenucci: thanks. I updated Question as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is related to your use of the "up navigation" (ie: arrow in menu bar)  as opposed to using the BACK button. I assume that, if you press the BACK button to return to your `MainActivity`, everything works as you want.

You should just disable the use of "up navigation" by removing:

```
android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
```

from the `<activity>` declaration in the manifest.

When you learn more about how you can customize the behaviour of the "up navigation", then you can ensure that when you use it to go back, a new instance of the previous `Activity` is not created, but the existing instance is reused.

Comment: I can confirm using system [<] Back button works as expected. If You can point me to relevant info on how to (correctly) enable "up navigation" I'll gladly accept You r answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can store the state of the MainActivity and start the child with startActivityForResult().

Here's an example in kotlin (I have omitted the non related part of the code) :

```
class ProductDataActivity : BaseActivity(),ProductDataFragment.ProductDataListener {

    private var productData: ProductBinding? = null

    companion object {
        private const val INSTANCE_STATE_PRODUCT_DATA = "state_product_data"
        private const val RESULT_DATA = 1
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
        outState?.putSerializable(INSTANCE_STATE_PRODUCT_DATA, this.productData)
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        this.productData = savedInstanceState?.getSerializable(INSTANCE_STATE_PRODUCT_DATA) as ProductBinding
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onDataClicked() {
        val intent = TabProductDetailsActivity.getCallingIntent(this, productData!!, false)
        this.startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_DATA)
    }
```

And the other activity:

```
class TabProductDetailsActivity : BaseActivity() {

    private var productData: ProductBinding? = null //The activity is started with an intent as you can see above in the ProducDataActivity.

   companion object {
        const val INTENT_EXTRA_PRODUCT_DATA = "intent_product_data"
    }

   override fun onBackPressed() {
        val resultIntent = Intent()
        resultIntent.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_PRODUCT_DATA, productData)
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent)
        finish()
    }
```

I hope you can understand what i'm doing here, basically i'm passing an object from one activity to another and when i press the back button i don't have a problem initiating the activity. Not sure if exactly this what you want, but i think it gives some light in one of the many approachs you can have.

Comment: I can understand what You are saying. AFAIK this is required to pass some custom data back to initiating Activity; it should *not* be necessary for widget properties; notice onCreate() is *not* called when I back-navigate. Also: I'm unsure the call to 'finish()' is correct as child activity is going to be destroyed anyways very soon.

Comment: Hm, i see your point. Maybe if you show us yout activity code we'll have more insight to help.

About the finish(), in this case i used it  because i had overriden completely the on back pressed.

Comment: Please look at the UPDATEs. I am now working with plain [MyFirstApp)(https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity), so "my code" is irrelevant (I can pastebin, if needed, but there's clutter there). I just added some 'Log.i()' messages to trace Activity lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out "culprit" is usage of `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` which *seems* (after a lot of debugging) to unconditionally call `requestDestroy()` at the end of `dispatchMessage()` called at the end of the chain initiated by `startActivity(intent)`.

Default implementation of `onSaveInstanceState()` dutifully saves widget status in a `Bundle`, but that is *not* passed to `MainActivity.onCreate(null)`.

Making `public class MainActivity extends Activity { ...` (instead of `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity`) cures the problem (it also throws havoc to `ActionBar` and other components, but that's another story).

Comment: Actually no. If you don't inherit from `AppCompatActivity` there are all kinds of stuff that won't work for you. In modern Android you MUST inherit from `AppCompatActivity` to obtain the expected look and feel and behaviour. See my answer for a solution to your problem.

Comment: @DavidWasser: I already supposed that much, but official documentation seem to imply "(back|up)-navigation" should work out-of-the-box. This is obviously untrue; any pointer welcome.